# Backgroundworker halts in between

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am starting a process lets say abc.exe in a background worker. In the beginning everything works fine but in between the newly created process i.e. abc.exe halts. Although I am starting abc.exe as hidden window but I come to know about its hang as it stops doing log writing.

When I close my UI form then again abc.exe starts working.

Can anybody tell me what could be the possible cause for this?

I am not able to debug the issue as it can happen at any time, I can not replicate it.

Please tell me as it is very urgent for me. If some more info is required then please revert back.

Comment: Can you show us the code that starts your process?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with background worker which is for creating threads, not processes. I suspect you are trying to use the StdIn/StdOut of the process you created?

It is common for a process to hang like that if you aren't reading from the standard output stream correctly. [There's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) of how to do this correctly and avoid deadlocks on MSDN.

Comment: I suppose you are saying right because I tried to read the output sent by abc.exe but that did not worked. I will remove that part then will try again and let you know. But thanks for your quick reply as it has given me new hope.